# É possível passar texto (json) via socket de cliente para cliente com javascript?

Tags: javascript

Enviar dados via socket, de um cliente para outro, apenas com javascript? De preferência, em js puro.

Sim, Sergio. Sem o servidor.

Comment: Quando dizes _de um cliente para outro_ queres dizer "sem ter um servidor a coordenar"?

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível passar um texto de cliente para cliente somente com javascript sem um servidor que atua como "ponte". O que você poderia fazer para não ter que lidar com o servidor, é usar serviços como por exemplo: [Pusher](https://pusher.com/), onde o seu trabalho seria basicamente a de integrar em seu aplicativo usando a API disponibilizada.

Sobre o Pusher: até 100 conexões simultâneos e 200 mil interações (messages) ainda entra no plano gratuito.